# p-value adjustment of spearman correlation matrix

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance

I have the following problem: I have a set of several observations A, B, C, ... (6 such observations) of a group of individuals (20 of such individuals). Since I am interested in whether there exist monotonic relationships (A vs B, A vs C,... B vs C, etc) among these observations I have run an spearman rank correlation test and I have obtained a correlation matrix with the corresponding 15 p-values. Certainly I have to correct these p-values for multiple testing. Bonferroni is an option.. However, are there other appropriate, not so conservative, tests in this scenario?

Methods as BH, etc.. assume that the variables are independent, which I understand is not the case here.

Comment: Are you trying to control the family wise error rate or the false discovery rate? BH doesn't require that variables are independent. If they were independent, Bonferroni would provide efficient control of the FWER.

Comment: @AdamO I would like to control the false discovery rate since I consider the study exploratory. As for the BH method... according to [link](http://www.biostathandbook.com/multiplecomparisons.html) "*The Bonferroni correction and Benjamini-Hochberg procedure assume that the individual tests are independent of each other, as when you are comparing sample A vs. sample B, C vs. D, E vs. F, etc. If you are comparing sample A vs. sample B, A vs. C, A vs. D, etc., the comparisons are not independent; if A is higher than B, there's a good chance that A will be higher than C as well.*"